# Init method with parameters not called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I spent hours trying to solve this issue
I'm trying to initialize a class with a parameter

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Fetch the value of the selected row in NSString
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   // NSString *tableRowValue = cell.text;
     tableRowValue = [[listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey: @"clientId"];


    //Call the next view

    ContactsList *contactsList = [[ContactsList alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([ContactsList class]) bundle:nil];
    @try {

        [self presentModalViewController:contactsList animated:YES];
    }
    @catch (NSException *ex) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ex]
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }



    contactsList.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve ;

    //Initialize the view with the clicked row value thwough NSString variable
    [contactsList init:tableRowValue];

}
```

this line of code

```
[contactsList init:tableRowValue];
```

I am getting the following warning :Expression result unused

and in ContactsList class the init method is not being called

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you want to suppress the warning you can prepend with (void). I'd change your method name though. init is used to instantiate objects. If you want to add a variable then use `intiWithTableRowValue:tableRowValue`

Comment: Thank you, I edited my code. the ViewDidLoad method is being called before the init method

Comment: because you are calling presentModalViewController before intiWithTableRowValue.

Answer (score 0):

The ContactList object is already initialized in the initWithNibName: method, which in turn calls the init method inherited from NSObject (with no parameters).

If you need to setup your view after initialization create a method named "setupWithTableRowValue:" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You should not called `init` in that way. `init` is supposed to be called first after the object is allocated and never again. In your case `init` was called already by means of `initWithNibName`.

Use some setter instead. Your setter does not need to return anything. 
init always returns id. So 
contactsList = [contactsList init:tableRowValue];
would be fine IF and only IF this was called directly after 
contactList = [ContactsList alloc];
because `init` actually may return an other object than the one for which it was invoked. You did not use the return value and therefor could -theoretically- loose your object.

Again: use a setter or similar method for passing `tableRowValue` to `contactsList`.